# How do I get a grid/lines UNDERNEATH my pdf pages in pdfpages?

Tags: pdfpages, eso-pic

I'm importing my lecture slide PDFs into LaTeX to edit them into a form more friendly for digital notetaking; that is, have 4 slides to a page with room to the side for writing.

This is not an issue and is accomplished easily; the issue is that I need lines to write on rather than blank white space. The closest I've come to making something usable is with eso-pic, THE PROBLEM is that if I use 'grid' the grid lines overlap my lecture slides, and if I use 'gridBG' which is supposed to be in the background, I simply have no grid lines at all:

[image: grid]

[image: gridBG]

The grid lines are overlapping my slides making it hard to read/look at.

So, my pages can be either grids or lines, I don't care. I just want some straight lines I can write on and if possible, adjust the spacing of. I can't figure out how to do it, it seems that the issue is trying to get between the original PDF and the new PDF output by pdfpages. I've tried pagecommand to no avail, and I've tried other grid packages too.

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{minimal}

\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in]{geometry}

\usepackage[gridBG,
      gridcolor=red!20,
      subgridcolor=black!20,
      gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[trim=0 0 0 0, clip, pages=-, nup=1x4, offset= -5.5cm 0, scale=0.95, delta=0cm 1cm, frame=true]{module4.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The option handling is a bit curious. To get a background grid you need both `grid` and `gridBG`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in]{geometry}

\usepackage[grid,gridBG,
      gridcolor=red!20,
      subgridcolor=black!20,
      gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[trim=0 0 0 0, clip, pages=-, nup=1x4, offset= -5.5cm 0, scale=0.95, delta=0cm 1cm, frame=true]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that makes me feel a bit silly. It's my first time using LaTeX though. That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible options is to use the package `background`. Makes it easy to set up the grid on the page.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{minimal}

\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in]{geometry}

%%************************************************* added
 \usepackage{tikz}  
\newcommand{\mygraphpaper}{%Make a grid
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=.4pt,draw=black!30] (0,0) grid[step=2em] (\textwidth,\textheight);
        \draw[line width=.4pt,draw=red!50] (0,0) grid[step=20em] (\textwidth,\textheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{background} %Put a grid in the background
\backgroundsetup{contents=\mygraphpaper, opacity=0.3, scale=1,  angle=0, vshift=0.0cm, hshift=10.0cm}

 %%*************************************************

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[trim=0 0 0 0, clip, pages=-, nup=1x4, offset= -5.5cm 0, scale=0.95, delta=0cm 1cm, frame=true]{Lecture.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Or

[image: c]

Using

```
%%************************************************* added
 \usepackage{tikz}  

\newcommand{\mygraphpaper}{%Make lines
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,0.7,...,40}{%
            \draw[line width=.4pt,draw=black!30,] (0.5\textwidth,\x)--(\textwidth,\x);
    }
        \foreach \x in {0,7,...,40}{%
    \draw[line width=.4pt,draw=red!50,] (0.5\textwidth,\x)--(\textwidth,\x);
}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{background} %Put lines in the background
\backgroundsetup{contents=\mygraphpaper, opacity=0.3, scale=1, angle=0, vshift=6.0cm, hshift=5.0cm}

 %%*************************************************
```

To make a complete compilable example for other users I include `Lecture.tex`

```
%%% file Lecture.tex

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{One}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}       
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Two}
        \kant[9]
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Three}
    \begin{eqnarray}
        \nonumber \Phi_T(\psi)=(\gamma_T\sqrt{\psi}) & \nonumber B=\frac{U}{2\omega_HL_c}\\ 
        \nonumber \omega_H=a_0\sqrt{\frac{A_c}{V_pL_c}} &\nonumber \gamma_T=Asin\left[\omega t\right]+b\\
    \end{eqnarray}  
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Four}
    \begin{tikzpicture}    
        \draw [thick] (0,4)--(2,4)--(2,5.5)--(4,5)--(4,4)--(7,4)--(7,5.5)--(9.5,5.5)--(9.5,4);
        \draw [thick] (0,3)--(2,3)--(2,1.5)--(4,2)--(4,3)--(7,3)--(7,1.5)--(9.5,1.5)--(9.5,3);   
        \draw [thick] (9.3,3)--(9.7,4);
        \draw [thick] (9.3,3)--(9.7,3);
        \draw [thick] (9.3,4)--(9.7,4);  
        \node[text width=3cm] at (1.5,3.6) {$\phi$};
        \node[text width=3cm] at (11.5,3.6) {$\Phi(\psi)$};      
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution and is probably nicer on the eyes than eso-pic. Thank you.